# How to Harden Apache against security vulnerabilities

Tags: apache, configuration, ddos, mod-security, hsts

We have an APache 2.4.6 version installed on Rhel 7.5 in production.
The security Audit team found few vulnerabilities lately which needs to be fixed.

1.) During audit ,it is observed that connect web server is vulnerable to Slowloris attack.
Mitigation suggested for this:
Rate limit incoming requests - Restricting access based on certain usage factors will help mitigate a Slowloris attack. Techniques such as limiting the maximum number of connections a single IP address is allowed to make, restricting slow transfer speeds, and limiting the maximum time a client is allowed to stay connected are all approaches for limiting the effectiveness of low and slow attacks.

2.)The lack of HSTS allows downgrade attacks, SSL-stripping man-in-the-middle attacks, and weakens cookie-hijacking protections.
Mitigation: Configure the remote web server to use HSTS response header.

3.) During the audit, it is observed that mod_security is not implemented which is an application security firewall for apache.
Mitigation:
Implement Mod_security to timely detect and prevent application security attacks.

I dont have much idea on how to configure these.
Please help me with the steps for getting the above issues fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I can point you in the right direction, perhaps, but the full configuration/setup for two of these is not short-checklist-friendly.

1) mod_qos is a way to limit your exposure to slowloris. It's designed to be used in a reverse_proxy server. Not sure if it fits your situation, but it's a place for you to start looking. I'm not sure total immunity to slowloris can be achieved, at least not without the potential for spending lots of money on it.

http://mod-qos.sourceforge.net

2) This one is easy. For apache, put this in the site configuration file:

```
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15638400"
```

That essentially tells the user-agent to never even think about using http, only https, on this site for the next 6 months (roughly).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security

3) mod_security should be available in one of the RHEL repos (probably EPEL) setup and configuration of that can get complex, so start here:

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)

(It's the manual for version 2.x, there's a 3.x but I suspect it's not made it into RHEL yet, so I'm posting the 2.x version)